# Keystrokes and commands for my inputrc — key-combination for “Shift-Space”, remap “Ctrl-PageUp/PageDown” to something without Page-keys

Tags: bash, terminal, terminal.app, readline, inputrc

I need to add some things to my inputrc. I'm using bash 4, as OS I'm using debian and OSX. My terminal emulators are rxvt-unicode-256 on debian and Terminal.app on OSX. My new macbook has no Insert/Delete, Home/End, PgUp/PgDown keys...

Could you please tell me the keystroke for "Shift-Space"? I'm trying to bind this to menu-complete-backward. Shift-Tab does menu-complete, the keystroke for this is "\e[Z".

```
"\e[Z": menu-complete
"(Shift-Space)": "\e-1\C-i"
```

Then I'd like to be able to go page up/down in my terminal. I'm not sure, how to say that. E.g. in irssi I'd like to scroll up/down in my channel log. The keys "PgUp"/"PgDn" do these, but I don't have those keys on my macbook. So I'd like an alternative, like maybe "Shift-ArrowKeyUp" and "Shift-ArrowKeyDown". Also I don't know the commands for inputrc, which I have to bind to this keystroke.

Same for "Home"/"End" keys which should go to beginning-/end-of-line. I'd like to bind that to maybe "Shift-ArrowKeyLeft"/"Shift-ArrowKeyRight".

Thanks very much for your help!

EDIT: Here's my .inputrc ... http://paste.debian.net/69454/

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: i am also wondering the same thing, and the answer is incorrect

Answer (score -1):

## Solution

Before I start with my solution, just a quick note here. Many of the commands you listed above (such as the Page Up/Down) don't have a `.inputrc` variable. They also already have corresponding shortcuts (see below). Therefore, if you want to use a different shortcut, you will have to remap the menu item to a new one.

### For Mac OS

#### Shortcuts

First of all, the Mac OS terminal has a built in keyboard shortcut for scrolling up and down the page: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>ArrowKeyUp</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>ArrowKeyDown</kbd>. Below is a quick table highlighting some of the menu commands and their corresponding shortcuts in the Mac Terminal:

```
|        Function         |        Shortcut        |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
|         Page Up         |      Command + Up      |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
|        Page Down        |     Command + Down     |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
|         Line Up         |  Shift + Command + Up  |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
|        Line Down        | Shift + Command + Down |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
| Go to beginning of line |      Control + A       |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
|    Go to end of line    |      Control + B       |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
```

#### New Shortcuts

If you don't want to use the built-in shortcuts, you will have to create new ones. There are several ways to do this, but I think using the GUI (versus the CLI) is easier in this situation. On Mac OS, open `System Preferences`, head to the `Keyboard` section, and finally click open the `Shortcuts` tab:

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

On the sidebar, click the `App Shortcuts` tab. Below, you will find a `+` button. Click that, and the following will pop up:

[image: Add Shortcut]

Choose Terminal from the dropdown menu, and type in the menu item and keyboard shortcut you want to map to it. Below is an example of mapping `Page Up` to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ArrowKeyUp</kbd>:

[image: New Shortcut]

### For Debian

#### Shortcuts

Like Mac OS, Debian already has all of the shortcuts you want built-in. Below is another table highlighting these shortcuts:

```
|        Function         |        Shortcut        |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
|         Page Up         |       Shift + Up       |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
|        Page Down        |      Shift + Down      |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
|         Line Up         |  Shift + Control + Up  |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
|        Line Down        | Shift + Control + Down |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
| Go to beginning of line |      Control + A       |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
|    Go to end of line    |      Control + B       |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
```

#### New Shortcuts

To create a new shortcut in Debian, use the GUI. Open up `Settings`, head to `Devices`, and then `Keyboard`. The following will show up:

[image: New shortcut in Debian]

Scroll down to the bottom, and click the `+` button. A dialog box will show up with the entry fields:

- Name
- Command
- Shortcut

Fill these out, click the blue `Add` button, and you're done.

Comment: They're looking for "shift + space". Not "shift + up arrow".